# How to cast from longlong to Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Control ^?

Tags: uwp

Or from Platform::Object ^ to Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Control ^ ?

I get an exception when I cast from Object ^ to Control ^

Comment: I can convert from longlong to Platform::Object ^ but then from Platform::Object ^ to Control ^ it raises an exception

Comment: If done from a Method then it works: void BlankUniversalAppCpp1::MainPage::button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e) { MyHandleEvent( ( Control ^ ) sender ); }

Comment: but when done from a function it raises the exception: char * GetCtrlName(Platform::Object ^ oCtrl)
{
 return WideToAnsi((LPWSTR)( ( Control ^) oCtrl )->Name->Data());
}

Comment: if you wonder why I have to do it this way, well basically I am building an interface for www.harbour-project to UWP

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used void * instead of longlong and also used this:

reinterpret_cast( hb_parptr( 1 ) )

hb_parptr() is a Harbour function and returns the void *